# pcap_next return NULL

Tags: linux, libpcap

I am working in openwrt with libpcap 1.5.3.

I have init pcap as following:

```
handle = pcap_create(capnic, errbuf);
if(!handle) {
    sys_err("pcap_create failed:%s\n", errbuf);
    exit(-1);
}

if(pcap_set_snaplen(handle, BUFSIZE)) {
    sys_err("pcap_set_snaplen failed\n");
    exit(-1);
}

if(pcap_activate(handle)) {
    sys_err("pcap_activate failed: %s\n",
        pcap_geterr(handle));
    exit(-1);
}
```

and capture packet with `pcap_next`:

```
struct pcap_pkthdr hdr;
const u_char * sysbuf;
if(!(sysbuf = pcap_next(handle, &hdr))) {
    sys_err("recv packet failed\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The program could catch packets, but there's a lot of error info:

```
recv packet failed
```

I have checked block state with function `pcap_getnonblock`, the handle is `block`.

Answer (score 1):

To quote the pcap_next()/pcap_next_ex() man page on my machine:

```
   pcap_next_ex() returns 1 if the packet was read without problems, 0  if
   packets are being read from a live capture, and the timeout expired, -1
   if an error occurred while reading the packet, and -2  if  packets  are
   being  read  from a ``savefile'', and there are no more packets to read
   from the savefile.  If -1 is returned, pcap_geterr()  or  pcap_perror()
   may be called with p as an argument to fetch or display the error text.

   pcap_next() returns a pointer  to  the  packet  data  on  success,  and
   returns  NULL  if  an  error occured, or if no packets were read from a
   live capture (if, for example, they were discarded because they  didn't
   pass the packet filter, or if, on platforms that support a read timeout
   that starts before any packets arrive, the timeout expires  before  any
   packets  arrive, or if the file descriptor for the capture device is in
   non-blocking mode and no packets were available to be read), or  if  no
   more  packets are available in a ``savefile.''  Unfortunately, there is
   no way to determine whether an error occured or not.
```

Note especially

> `pcap_next()` ... returns  NULL  if  an  error occured, *or if no packets were read from a live capture (if, for example, they were discarded because they  didn't pass the packet filter, or if, on platforms that support a read timeout that starts before any packets arrive, the timeout expires before any packets  arrive...)

Note also

> Unfortunately, there is no way to determine whether an error occured or not.

which is the man page's way of telling you that you should probably be using `pcap_next_ex()`, which *does* distinguish between those two cases.